# change all the list values to the last value

Tags: c

so i have a code that a little bit confused, so i build a struct :

```
typedef struct{
char *team_name;
}Team;
```

and other struct :

```
typedef struct{
Team** teams;
int num_teams;
}League;
```

and a function that create the struct Team:

```
Team* TeamCreate(char* team_n)
{
Team* t=(Team*)malloc(sizeof(Team));
t->team_name =team_n;
return t;
}
```

also for League struct:

```
League* LeagueCreate()
{
League* l=(League*)malloc(sizeof(League));
return l;
}
```

and the worst part is this function that should insert a words of text file into    'Team** teams' 
so in every value of `teams` there is `Team` value that contain this word as `char *team_name`.
and the function make all teams list value equal to the last value of teams list.
the function:

```
void read_teams(League* l,char* text)
{
FILE *fp=fopen(text,"r");
char* tname=NULL;
size_t tname_size=0;
l->num_teams=0;
l->teams=NULL;
while(getline(&tname,&tname_size,fp)!=EOF)
{
    char *p= strchr(tname,'\n');
    if (p)
        tname[p-tname]='\0';
    l->teams=(Team**)realloc(l->teams,sizeof(Team*)*(l->num_teams+1));
    l->teams[l->num_teams]=TeamCreate(tname);
    l->num_teams++;
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

so for example my text file is :

```
Napoli
Salzburg
Liverpool
Genk
```

and when i write :

```
printf("\n%s\n",l->teams[0]->team_name);
printf("\n%s\n",l->teams[1]->team_name);
printf("\n%s\n",l->teams[2]->team_name);
printf("\n%s\n",l->teams[3]->team_name);
```

it print this:

```
Genk
Genk
Genk
Genk
```

and thanks for your time :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you call `getline`, sufficient space to hold the line will be allocated for you.  Unless subsequent calls realloc the memory, you're passing the same exact pointer `TeamCreate` every time.  Therefore, all of your `Team`s have the same `char*` and therefore the same `team_name`.  Every time you update the string via `getline`, all of the `team_name`s will change since they reference the same string.

What you need to do in `TeamCreate` is use the `strdup` function from `string.h` so that each `Team` gets its own string.  I.e.,

```
t->team_name = strdup(team_n);
```

Comment: but i keep Team* t=(Team*)malloc(sizeof(Team)); right?

Comment: Yes, although you don't need the `(Team*)` cast.

Comment: yeah, but that what i asked for,thank you ,you sloved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read a .txt file line by line.

```
#define MAXCHAR 1000
char* filename = "G:\\test.txt";

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", str);
    fclose(fp);
```